# combine mutiple tables with different column in to one table

Tags: sql, database-trigger

I have three tables that contain totally different data with different header column.

- table 1) SQL_1  with columns: col_1,col_2,col_3
- table 2) SQL_2  with columns: col_4,col_5,col_6
- table 3) SQL_3  with columns: col_7,col_8

I need a query (or a trigger) to insert all these data from these three tables to final_table. I can do these when all tables have the same column, but not with different columns header.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could this be as simple as (for a new table)

```
select *
into new_table
from sql_1, sql_2, sql_3
```

If you have a table created, then you can populate it with:

```
insert into new_table (col_1, col_2, col_3, etc.,)
select col_1, col_2, col_3, etc.,
from sql_1, sql_2, sql_3
```

(adjust the column names to suit)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, this creates a new table, but I want to insert into existing table.

Comment: Updated my answer to include the same style for an existing table.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `UNION` statement and aliases:

```
INSERT INTO final_table
SELECT col_1 AS c1, col_2 AS c2, col_3 AS c3 FROM SQL_1
UNION
SELECT col_4 AS c1, col_5 AS c2, col_6 AS c3 FROM SQL_2
UNION
SELECT col_7 AS c1, col_8 AS c2, NULL AS c3 FROM SQL_3
```

And choose the column aliases to match the column names in `final_table`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. On this one I get error: Incorrect syntax near keyword 'select', incorrect syntax near')'.   is this a trigger?